# ADB not responding in intellij 14

Tags: android, intellij-idea

i have an error in my intellij 14 when run my project , this error is :

```
ADB not responding. If you'd like to retry, then please manually kill "adb" and click 'Restart
```

i searched and found it to solve that :

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-i386 lib32stdc++6 lib32gcc1 lib32ncurses5

sudo apt-get install lib32z1
```

but i have error when run commands :

```
Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/e/eglibc/libc6-i386_2.19-0ubuntu6.3_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
```

Comment: try `sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32z1-dev lib32stdc++6`

Comment: @sufiyan i try that but i get error again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead,

```
sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6
```

If that doesn't work then,

- Try disabling your firewall if you have one
- Run Intellij as the administrator.
- Run `adb kill-server` and then `adb start-server` from your command
  line
- Also run this command in your terminal:

`sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6`

When you do that, you might be warned by the installer that the package is obsolete and suggests alternatives and you can then install them (they are three libraries).
Another thing to try is this:

```
sudo apt-get install lib32ncurses5
```

Also, if you still have issues, go to the folder that contains `adb` and change its file permission to Allow executing file as a program).

If nothing mentioned above worked, run this command to install other libraries that might be missing:

```
sudo apt-get install libncurses5:i386
```

If none of the above mentioned method works then you should consult this,
[How-To: Install Google's Android Eclipse Plugin (And/or Adb) on 64-bit Debian/Ubuntu](http://blog.timmattison.com/archives/2011/11/02/how-to-install-googles-android-eclipse-plugin-and-or-adb-on-64-bit-debian-ubuntu/)

Comment: i try it , but when i want use abd kill-server , i get this error : No command 'abd' found and when test ./abd , get error : ./abd: No such file or directory

Comment: my abd permission is : -rwxrwxr-x

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to reinstall.

1) Close IntelliJ

2) In your terminal, navigate to your sdk platform-tools

3) Use 'adb kill-server'

4) Use 'adb start-server'

5) Restart IntelliJ

Comment: i try it , but when i want use abd kill-server , i get this error :     No command 'abd' found and when test ./abd , get error : ./abd: No such file or directory

Comment: Did you make sure to navigate to your sdk platform-tools?
C:\...\android-sdk\platform-tools